# how do i find on the same table a record that exist for both criterias and display them in the same row under different column name

Tags: sql

I've been battling with this sql problem that is probably easy for a database person but i have not been able to rap my mind around it.  I created a self join to the table itself and with a having distinct statement but no luck

Here is in a diagram view below on what i'm trying to achieve.  If someone can also give me direction on why of it all that would also be great to. Thanks

For my criteria I only want to choose the only usernames that have both 'IL' and 'ND' codes on the Table.  If they just have 'IL' and no 'ND' then they should 
not be included in my dataset.  After getting those accounts, i want to display there infor in one row like this
and if they have more then either 2 or more IL or ND accts I just want to choose 1 of them to display.

```
 username     Code      MyAcctNumber
------------------------------------
user1        IL         10277
user1        ND         19754
user1        BD         19542
user3        IL         10377
user4        IL         10477
user4        ND         18756
user4        ND         19854
user4        NF         18745
user5        IL         95423
user5        ND         74152
user5        BC         18745
```

Here is how my results set table would look like

```
username       NDAcctNumer      ILAccNumber
------------------------------------------
user1          19754            10277
user4          18756            10477 
user5          74152            95423
```

Comment: I would start by picking a database and sticking with it (i.e don't tag MySQL **and** SQL Server - please choose one...)

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user `INNER JOIN` with the table itself to achieve this, something like this :

```
select 
    a.username as username, min(a.myacctnumber) as NDAcctNumer, min(b.myacctnumber) as ILAccNumber 
from 
    Table1 a
inner join 
    (
          select 
              username, code, myacctnumber 
          from 
              Table1 
          where 
              code = 'IL'
          group by 
              username, code, myacctnumber
    ) b 
    on 
        a.username = b.username
where 
    a.code = 'ND'
group by 
    a.username
order by
    username asc
```

This will result in :

```
------------------------------------------------------
|   username   |    NDAcctNumer   |    ILAccNumber   |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|    user1     |      19754       |      10277       |
|    user4     |      18756       |      10477       |
|    user5     |      74152       |      95423       |
------------------------------------------------------
```

---

You can refer to this [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecd4d/12) to try this out.

Comment: Thanks Satish.  This solution makes perfect sense on why i was not solving my problem.  ~W

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone, so please forgive typos.

You can use `GROUP BY` to squash the records to a single row per `username`.

Then you can use `MIN()` combined with a `CASE` statement to pick out each field.

```
SELECT
    username,
    MIN(CASE code WHEN 'ND' THEN myacctnumber END)  AS NDAcctNumber,
    MIN(CASE code WHEN 'IL' THEN myacctnumber END)  AS ILAcctNumber
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    username
```

If you really MUST exclude cases that only have one or other account number, you can either wrap an outer query around the one above, or use append a `HAVING` clause

```
HAVING
        MAX(CASE code WHEN 'ND' THEN 1 END) = 1
    AND MAX(CASE code WHEN 'IL' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

This avoids the need for potentially expensive joins.

If, however, you KNOW that a VERY small percentage of usernames have both account types, then the JOIN version can be faster.  (Filter to a very low number of rows, then join.)